# WD Edition of Acronis True Image makes unbootable drive

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, mbr, clone, acronis-trueimage

https://support.wdc.com/knowledgebase/answer.aspx?ID=10445 indicates the ***WD edition*** of Acronis True Image will not be a bootable drive. How might a cloned drive (MBR partition table, not GPT, since original created with Windows 7) imaged with this app be made bootable?

Note: Had [I restored onto a new SSD using Acronis True Image Home, but it won't boot; how do I make the system boot from the new SSD?](https://superuser.com/questions/922709/i-restored-onto-a-new-ssd-using-acronis-true-image-home-but-it-wont-boot-how) solved the problem according to its original poster, I would think that a reasonable solution. When I read it before posting, I saw it did not, and had multiple contradictory answers, therefore, since there's no canonical answer, don't believe this is a duplicate.

Comment: https://superuser.com/users/74377/justin-pearce Had that solved the problem according to its original posted, I would think that a reasonable solution. When I read it before posting, I saw it did not, therefore, don't believe this is a duplicate.

Comment: Try the solutions listed there (they could work in your case), then report the results. I'd give you the same suggestions: Windows autorepair, `fixmbr`, set partition to active, `diskpart`. Or use an [alternative tool](https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html).